# Exclude all instances of a class from serialization in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is there a possibility with Newtonsoft JSON to mark a certain class with an annotation such that properties of the type of this class are never serialized. Of course it is possible to put the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute above all properties. But it would be interesting whether something similar would be possible on class level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every custom type can opt how it will be serialized.

To example, mark the type with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` and then you have to mark something with `[JsonProperty]` otherwise **nothing** will be serialized. So even if property of custom type is serializable the type may produce nothing (`{}`) to serialize:

```
public class A
{
    public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";
    public B B { get; set; } = new B();
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class B
{
    public string Foo { get; set; } = "Foo";
}
```

and then

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new A()));
```

will produce

> {"Test":"Test","B":{}}"

With this approach you will have problems to serialize `B` at all. Which is not very bright idea, don't you think?

Comment: Like this properties of with type B will still be serialized, only they will have no properties which is not quite the same what I ask for but it's a good alternative. Thx! But regarding to whether it is a bright idea depends on the use case I'd say.