# how to tell JsonSerializer to ignore all properties that are of a given type?

Tags: c#, json

Basically what I want is something like below

```
    [SomeJsonIgnoreAnnotation]
    class MySecret {
      public int Secret { get; set; } = 1;
    }

    class A {
      public MySecret SecretA { get; set; } = new();
    }

    class B {
      public MySecret SecretB { get; set; } = new();
    }
```

And `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` would treat class `A` and class `B` as if `SecretA` and `SecretB` are annotated with `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673758/exclude-all-instances-of-a-class-from-serialization-in-newtonsoft-json

Comment: @ddastrodd tried to find similar feature in `JsonSerializer` with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The simple solution:**

```
class MySecret {
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Secret { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Now the property `Secret` will never be serialized by any class using the class `MySecret`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Newtonsoft.Json and have many properties it is more effective to use a DataContract attribute instead of JsonIgnore

```
   [DataContract]
    public class MySecret
    {
        public int Secret { get; set; } = 1;

    }
```

test

```
    var a = new A();
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a); // {"SecretA":{}}
```

if you still want to serialize some members you can add DataMember attribute

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class MySecret
{
    public int Secret { get; set; } = 1;

    [DataMember]
    public int SecretShow { get; set; } = 2;
}
```

test

```
{"SecretA":{"SecretShow":2}}
```

Comment: This is `Json.NET` right? as `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter` don't have `SerializeObject` method. I tried it for `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`, no luck.

Comment: Yes , it is working for Newtonsoft.Json only. System.Text.Json  needs lots of manual code to make something working. I highly recommend you to move to Newtonsoft.Json